# An asymptotics for $\sum_{N\leq p\leq 2N}\frac{1}{p^2}$ for primes in a residue class

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{p\text{ prime}\mid p\equiv a\pmod q\}$, $a\neq 0$, $q$ a prime. Then PNT gives us$$S:=\sum\limits_{p\leq x, \,  p\in\mathcal{A}}\frac{1}{p}=\frac{\log\log x}{\phi(q)}+c+O\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right).$$

I am working on a problem in which I have to find an asymptotics of $$\sum\limits_{N\leq p\leq 2N, \,  p\in\mathcal{A}}\frac{1}{p^2\left(\frac{23}{8}-\frac{5p}{4N}\right)}<\frac{8}{3}\sum\limits_{N\leq p\leq 2N, \,  p\in\mathcal{A}}\frac{1}{p^2},$$ $N\ge1$. But does there exist any asymptotics of $$\sum\limits_{p\leq x, \, p\in\mathcal{A}}\frac{1}{p^2}$$ similar to that of $S$?

P.S. I know that the sum would be smaller than $0.46$ but I am looking for something that would depend on $N$ like $1/\log N$ but this tends to $0$ as $N\to\infty$. That's causing some confusion. Moreover, $1/\log N+O(1)$ doesn't fit well with the rest of the problem.

Comment: There are approximately $\frac n{2(q-1)\log n}$ primes in that range, for each $\frac 1 {p^2}$ is between $\frac 1 {4n^2}$ and $\frac 1 {n^2}$, so the sum is asymptotically between $\frac1{8(q-1)n\log n}$ and $\frac1{2(q-1)n\log n}$. You can probably get tighter bounds by approximating the probability $p$ is in $A$ as $\frac1{\log p (q-1)}$ and integrating $\frac{1}{p^2 (q-1) \log p}$, which gives $E_1(\log n) - E_1(\log {2n})$

Comment: Cont. It's actually $\frac{1}{q-1}(E_1(\log n) - E_1(\log n + \log 2))$, which gives approximately $\frac{\log 2}{(q-1)n\log n}$. This isn't rigorous at all, but could probably be made so.

Comment: You could get rigorous results using Abel's summation formula on the prime indicator sequence and $\frac 1 {n^2}$.

Comment: "but this tends to $0$ as $N→∞$. That's causing some confusion." It is easy to see that your sum must tend to $0$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @Gary why is the sum tending to $0$? Does it have anything to do with the density of primes or simply the number of primes in the residue class $\mathcal{A}$ between $N$ and $2N$ for large values of $N$?

Comment: @AnishRay It is because $\sum_p 1/p^2$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if we use Abel's summation formula with $a_n = I_{\mathcal A}(n)$ and $\phi(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$, we get
$$\sum_{p\leq x, p\in A} \frac1{p^2} = \sum_{n\leq x}\frac {a_n} {n^2} = \frac{A(x)}{x^2} + 2\int_1^x{\frac{A(u)}{u^3}} du$$
According to Dirichlet's theorem, $A(n) = \frac n{\phi(q)\log n} + O(\frac n {\log^2(n)})$, so
$$\sum_{p\leq x, p\in A} \frac1{p^2} = \frac{1}{\phi(q) x \log x} + C + \frac2{\phi(q)}\int_2^x{\frac{1}{u^2 (\log u + \Omega(\log^2(u))}} du + O(\frac 1 {x \log^2(x)}) = \frac{1}{\phi(q) x \log x} + C_2 + \frac2{\phi(q)}\text{Ei}(-\log x) + O(\frac 1 {x \log^2(x)}) = \frac{1}{\phi(q) x \log x} + C_2 - \frac2{\phi(q)}\frac{1}{x \log x} (1 + O(\frac{1}{\log x})) + O(\frac 1 {x \log^2(x)}) = C_2 - \frac{1}{\phi(q) x \log x} + O(\frac1{x \log^2(x)})$$

Comment: By L'Hôpital's rule, it is easy to show that $$
\int_2^x {\frac{{{\rm d}u}}{{u^2 \log ^2 u}}}  = \int_2^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm d}u}}{{u^2 \log ^2 u}}}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x\log ^2 x}}} \right).
$$ So you can omit it (it just changes the value of $C_2$). What is $n$ in the argument of $\mathrm{Ei}$? For $\mathrm{Ei}(-z)$ it is better to write $E_1(z)$ and use [$(6.12.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.E1).

Comment: @Gary thanks. It should've been $x$, I fixed that.

Comment: @Gary $Ei(z) = -E_1(-z)$, so it's negative that.

Comment: Fixed: $$\frac{2}{{\varphi (q)}}{\rm Ei}( - \log x) =- \frac{2}{{\varphi (q)}}E_1 (\log x) = -\frac{2}{{\varphi (q)}}\frac{1}{{x\log x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x\log ^2 x}}} \right).$$ This will yield $$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\varphi (q)}}\frac{1}{{N\log N}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{N\log ^2 N}}} \right)
$$ for the OP's original question.